# Why does iron-selector not have a dom-module definition?

Tags: polymer

My IDE complains that iron-selector is an unknown html tag.  I see in the iron selector source that, indeed, there is no dom-module definition and that must be why I get the warning because none of the other polymer elements I've used produce such warnings.

Why is it that iron-selector does *not* need a dom-module definition?

Comment: Apparently, you are asking how to configure code intelligence for Polymer in a given IDE, but you don't even say the IDE name. Can you please edit the question and give some details?

Comment: iron-selector does not have a dom-module cause it is only importing behavior.

Comment: No not asking how to configure and IDE.  My question was clear. I'd like to understand web components, and Polymer, better.  Although I see I missed and a "not" (!). Fixed that.

Comment: Okay - I think I get it now. The Polymer function registers the element so it is recognized ("is:").  But no need for <dom-module> tag if no css or template.  Hence no "importing behaviour".  I see the same pattern in others, e.g. iron-ajax.